# How to get Video URL from a web page in python?

Tags: python, video-streaming

I need the video URL of a streaming video playing on a website.If I inspect in the network of the Chrome I can get the .m3u8 streaming URL,How do I achieve this Programatically using Python?

Answer (score 0):

For Python, check out [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which is an HTML parser library that can help you scrape webpages. It probably won't work though if the page is rendered client-side (will only get raw HTML, so if the website has JavaScript generating HTML dynamically, you will need something like Selenium or some wrapper around a web rendering engine like WebKit).